# Import python module into current project?

Tags: python, eclipse

I was wondering how I go about importing `SomeProjectInProgress.py` into `MyOtherProject.py`.

I'm using Eclipse Luna, if that makes any difference.  I know that I can `right-click > Import` on `MyOtherProject.py` and add the entire `SomeProjectInProgress.py` file into my project, but any changes I make to the original aren't reflected in the imported version.

Is there a way I can reference the original from within my project WITHOUT having to re-import every time I update the original?

*Apologies in advance if this has already been asked.  I've looked at the other four-or-so questions on imports, but none of them seem to specifically address this scenario*

Answer (score 1):

No you won't be able to achieve this.

1) You run your python file using `MyOtherProject.py` which has `import  SomeProjectInProgress` in it.

2) Python would create a `.pyc` files for all your imports and the same .pyc file will be used till the time your process(`MyOtherProject.py`) is running.

3) If you make any changes to `SomeProjectInProgress`, it will not be reflected till the time you don't restart your program.

Comment: Tanks for the clarification.  Just to be sure, if I run and complete  `MyOtherProject`, make changes to the import, then re-run `MyOtherProject`, you're saying it's impossible to reflect those changes in `MyOtherProject` without re-right-click-Importng the edited file?

Comment: `right-click-Importng`- not sure where are you running this. But yes for changes you need to restart(re import is not required, it will be imported automatically on start).